# Why does upload to s3 bucket fail with Node.js fail to write image data?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am writting this node script in order to upload images to an s3 bucket. So far so good, apart from the fact that the images that are uploaded on the bucket have 0 KB size. That means that I am able to see their names, however there is no content on the images. Could anyone give me some light as to why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('./config');



//configuring the AWS environment


var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey

  });


const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucket',
        Key: fileName, // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: fs.readFileSync(fileName)
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
};
uploadFile("car.png");
uploadFile("aeroplane.png");
uploadFile("sky.png");
```

I appreciate any help, as I really dont get what could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

reading the file as stream using `createReadStream` is working for me.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create S3 service object
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// Configure the file stream and obtain the upload parameters
const fs = require('fs');
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('/file/path');

fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});

var uploadParams = {
    Bucket: 'bucket-name', 
    Key: 'key', 
    Body: fileStream
};

s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } if (data) {
    console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
  }
});
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-example-creating-buckets-upload-file

Comment: Did you try this on one or multiple files?

Comment: i have hard coded one file name and executed. i tried it with two files

Comment: for me it works fine with one file. however when I try uploading multiple files is when the error appears

Comment: multiple files at the same time? , how are you doing it

Comment: got it, try to use promise to make it sequential

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your code works for me perfectly for multiple files. I have copied three image files in the same directory and ran your code. All files are copied to S3 as it is. None of those are zero bytes.

Comment: I think you have some file system permission issues when trying to access three files from the same directory. in order to confirm that, try moving the files to separate directories and run your code.

Comment: by the way, I have tested your code on a Mac computer